# Distribution proportional to size

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is almost too basic: Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with support $\{1,2,...,n-1\}$ such that

$$P(X=k)=k/N,$$

where $N:=\binom{n}{2}$. Does this distribution have a common name? It's also the exact opposite of Zipf's distribution. I've vaguely seen it come up as "PPS" ("probability proportional to size") sampling.

Comment: I would call this a *discrete triangular distribution*

Comment: For an example, see Question 1329253, the distribution of the size of Player A's team has this kind of triangular shape. Most triangular distributions seem to be the 'reverse' of yours, with higher probabilities for lower numbers.